# A list view which refreshes regularly?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my android app. I am trying to make a downloads page where it shows a listview containing all the downloaded files.

So the requirement is to refresh the list view on its own in regular intervals.

Is there any way to do that process without having any lag to the UI of the app.

Answer (score 0):

'You can do it by using the following function'

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

         //Your code which you want to refresh after a specific time

        }
    },5000);
```

'here i had set the time interval of 5 seconds which you can change according to your requirements'